# What is the best way to move this text nearby the logo?

Tags: html, css

currently I'm making a nav bar for a product landing page. And I can't get this " Johns auto service " to get placed near the car picture. When I try to add h1 or p tags then it pushes down out of the div. But when I dont add anything it stays there. So what is the best way to place it in the center right side of the picture like a logo I mean ( like a stackoverflow logo). Thanks for help.  And if there's anything I should change please tell me because I'm still learning this and any advice would be appreciated .

```css
 body {
        margin:0;
      }
      #header {
        display:flex;
        max-height:50px;
      }
      
      #nav-bar {
        width:40vw;
        justify-content:space-around;
        align-items:center;
      }
      .image {
        width:60vw;
        background-color:gray;
      }
      #header-img{
        width:50px;
      }
      
       ul {
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type:none;
        display:flex;
        justify-content:space-between;
      }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    <header id="header">
      <div class="image">
      <img id="header-img" src="http://clipart.9file.net/770ddeaed8e20e0b205be28ee31cdd9e/cliparts/225/medium/c1493845e027eb29be10ed911d0a015a.png">
        Johns auto service
      </div>
      <nav id="nav-bar">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">How it works</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Pricing</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      
    </header>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add display:inline-block to your p tag or h1 or whatever. So it stays inside the parent.

```
#header p {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I made an example, if this answers your question (not sure though messy request)

```
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XBBGrJ
```

Greets

Answer (score 1):

As far i can see you didn't declare your .css file in the head of the document. 
Add  in the head of your document.
styles.css can be anything you named your . css file.

Answer (score 0):

```
 You can check this fiddle
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Minal4/fvuojp8x/3/

If any questions please feel free to ask :)